# PyCharmでファイルを編集中、numpy.savetxt に対して表示されるエラーの解決方法を知りたい

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

PyCharmでPythonファイルを編集している時に下図のようにエラー報告（？）が出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
li_electには標準のリストが代入されていて、float型と日付のデータが入っています。
またnumpy.savetxt()は実行されcsvファイルも書き出されてはいます。
ただ、このエラー表示になっているのでとても気になって見た目に邪魔です。

解決方法やチェック事項などご存知ありましたらアドバイスいただきたく思います。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: PyCharm 2019.3.2(Community Edition) で同じ現象が発生していて、当該箇所にマウスカーソルを重ねると、`Expected type 'int', got 'ndarray' instead.` と表示されます。おそらく、[PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) にしたがって、型チェックを行っているのだと思います。一応、`numpy.savetxt()` の定義部分(`numpy/lib/npyio.py`)で型を指定すれば(`def savetxt(fname, X: np.ndarray, ...`)ハイライトされなくなりますが、numpy のソースコードを直接編集するのはよろしくないので、他の手段を考えた方が良いでしょう(例えば PyCharm の type checking 機能を全面的にオフにしてしまうなど)。

Comment: そうなのですか。やはりPyCharmの問題なのですね。
numpyのソースコードの編集などは私には怖くて手が出ません。
残念ですがsavetxt()を諦めて、Pandasでなんとかすることにしました。
原因が知ることができたので、その点のモヤモヤななくなり良かったです。
書き込みありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppressing-comments

PyCharmを使っていく前提なら、警告を抑制するコメントをそこに入れてしまってもいいかと思います。
(外し時が難しいのですけれど)

```py
x = np.array([1,2,3])

np.savetxt('hoge', x)  # これは警告が表示される

# noinspection PyTypeChecker
np.savetxt('hoge', x)  # これは警告が抑制される
```

エラーなどではなく、ただ警告が表示されているだけなので気にしなくてもいいと思いますが。